# Is the "beauty of design" a good phrase?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I was writing some words in my portfolio website. But I felt confused about this.

> In the time when I was coding my website, I've made several UI things. However, only after I entering this field, did I notice the beauty of design.

I was trying to express that when the time I built my website,  I've done some UI(user interface) techniques even though I didn't notice that. And after I really entered this field, I gradually knew how deep and beautiful of it.

Is there a better way to say it?

Comment: "... did I notice the peerless beauty of the design."

Comment: What is the website mainly about ... is its intended audience the type of people who might be interested in the ***beauty of the design*** of the UI coding? And it might well be designed beautifully, but you need some care in the specific expression so it doesn't sound quite so blowing-your-own-trumpet (bragging).

Comment: @Cargill Thanks. It's actually an intro with hyperlink to my Behance portfolio.

Comment: I would prefer the "elegance of [the] design". But, it's a matter of opininon.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my edits of your question and a possible solution. Please note that I am an editor, not a programmer, so I may have failed to capture your meaning correctly.

"I am writing an intro for my portfolio website, but I was confused by this:

While developing my website, I **created** several UI **improvements**. However, it was only after I became more experienced in coding that I noticed the beauty  **and elegance** of the design itself.

I was trying to express that while I was building my website, I had used some UI (user interface) techniques, although I didn't notice it at the time. And as I became more experienced in coding, I gradually began to see how deep and beautiful they are.

Is there a better way to say this?"

Comment: Thanks Mark! But I'm confused about “additions” in the second paragraph, what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Chenghuayang: Thank you for your question. "Additions," as I originally used it ("I made several UI additions"), means you added something to an existing user interface. Would "improvements" be more accurate? In other words, were you modifying code originally created by someone else to make your website easier to use and more elegant? I will edit my answer and highlight my changes in Bold.

Comment: (The edits to my answer are based on comments from you and others.)